# Changing the layer mask of a pointer in MRTK v2.1

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

I need to change the layer mask during runtime in order to select different objects depending on the context.
From my understanding this should be done in the `InputSystemProfile` by editing the Pointers property:

`CoreServices.InputSystem.InputSystemProfile.PointerProfile.PointingRaycastLayerMasks`

But the field is read-only, and I can't find another way to edit it, other than manually in the editor.
Btw I'm using an editable profile for the input system.

In HTK this was achieved by assigning a value to:
`GazeManager.Instance.RaycastLayerMasks`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the returned field `PointingRaycastLayerMasks`, it is an instance of reference type `LayerMask[]`. Therefore, although you cannot change the value of the reference itself, it is possible to change the data that belongs to that referenced object.

So, you can change Layer Mask with the following code:

```
//Uncheck [PostProcessing],[Spatial Awareness]
CoreServices.InputSystem.InputSystemProfile.PointerProfile.PointingRaycastLayerMasks[0].value = 19;
```

If you have questions about how to use LayerMasks in Unity, please see here: [How do I use layermasks?](https://answers.unity.com/questions/8715/how-do-i-use-layermasks.html)

Answer (score 1):

you could change the pointers layer mask by overriding it
All the pointers can by found here: CoreServices.InputSystem.DetectedInputSources
and in each one you can do:
ptr.PrioritizedLayerMasksOverride

Hope this helps